# Python Money class not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm confusing something with the Money class in Python. When trying to print, I get 'USD 100.00'. Then, to add the dollar sign, I format it in the second print statement. Then, to combine the 2 steps, I create another function that does both. But, the printout doesn't do the formatting I expect, which is just '$100.00' done in one step. I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
Class Week_Of_Meetings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weekly_cost_in_dollars = Money(100, self.CURRENCY)

    def weekly_cost_in_dollars(self):
        return self.weekly_cost_in_dollars

    def weekly_cost_in_dollars_2(self):
        return self.weekly_cost_in_dollars.format('en_US')
```

Then I import the class into another file and try calling it:

```
wom = Week_Of_Meetings(meetings)
print(wom.weekly_cost_in_dollars)
print(wom.weekly_cost_in_dollars.format('en_US'))
print(wom.weekly_cost_in_dollars_2)
```

And I get:

```
USD 100.00
$100.00
<bound method Week_Of_Meetings.weekly_cost_in_dollars_2 of 
    <model.week_of_meetings.Week_Of_Meetings instance at 0x10d3d7d40>>
```

Comment: Seems like you are confusing the meanings and concepts of classes, methods and attributes.

Comment: You get 3 lines of printouts because you call print three times? .. or are you confused about the result of the prints?

Comment: I'm confused about the result of the printouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def` defines a method; you're defining two of those: `weekly_cost_in_dollars` and `weekly_cost_in_dollars_2`. **However**, in `__init__` you're **replacing** `weekly_cost_in_dollars` with a plain value. When you access that plain value, you can obviously `.format` it directly. But `weekly_cost_in_dollars_2` is still a method, a *function*, which you need to call to get its result (`wom.weekly_cost_in_dollars_2()`).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!